# Combining mule expression language and literals

Tags: mulesoft

I am building an application using Mule 4.2.2 version where in I have to retrieve data from Mongo DB. For this I am using the MongoDB connector version 6.3.0. I am using the "Find Documents" as show in the image below, where you can see I have mentioned the query as

{"eventCode": $[vars.eventCode]} where eventCode is the field on which I am querying and eventCode is the variable where I am storing the incoming eventCode.

[image]

When I run the mule application I see an error in the logs that says -

```
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON input. Position: 15. Character: '#'.
```

I thought that I could combine literals and mule expressiong using #[], but that doesn't seem to work. Any pointers on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If it is an expression, then you can not use `#[...]` inside. Just write the expression:

```
{"eventCode": vars.eventCode}
```

If it is not an expression -if the fx button clicked?- you might need to enclose the entire expression into `#[...]`.

```
#[{"eventCode": vars.eventCode}]
```